# Can't bind to 'data-bs-target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear un acordeón con varios elementos que traigo de una base de datos, por lo que necesito que cada button expanda solo su propio contenido, pero a la hora de concatenar el atributo se muestra este error:

[image: Error que me salta al compilar]

Y este es el código:

```
<div class="summary-projects container lg">
    <div class="accordion" id="projectAccordion">
        <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let project of projects">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button  class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{{project.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    {{project.name}}
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapse{{project.id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#projectAccordion">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <table class="table">
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El error solo aparece al concatenar el project.id al #collapse con el

```
[data-bs-target]="'#collapse'+project.id"
```

igual manera ya probé con

```
data-bs-target="#collapse{{project.id}}"
```

y con las dos me da el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

Para los atributos `data-*`, como no tienen propiedad equivalente, tienes que usar el *vínculo de atributos*. El formato es igual que el vinculo de propiedades, pero añadiendo `attr.` delante del nombre del atributo al que quieras vincular.

En tu caso quedaría así

```
[attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse'+project.id"
```

un saludo

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda. Estuve horas pegado en esto